# Why do I get "Unknown option "–enable-static" " when trying to build the static ffmpeg library from source?

Tags: ffmpeg, g++, static-libraries

I want to link some ffmpeg code statically to my own executable using

`g++ -o myBin main.cpp ../libavformat.a ../libavcodec.a`

so I need to build the static libraries of ffmpeg first. I downloaded the ffmpeg source code from

`git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git`

but when running

`./configure –enable-static –enable-gpl –enable-libfaac –enable-libfaad –enable-libx264 –enable-nonfree`

I get the error `"Unknown option "–enable-static" ".`

How can I build the static libraries of ffmpeg correctly?

Comment: autoconf options are spelled with **two** leading dashes. `--enable-static` etc.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant What is that mean? "build the static libraries of ffmpeg".

Comment: @user2212461 What do you mean by "build the static libraries of ffmpeg"? Does it means have a ffmpeg executable that can use in specific OS, without any dependencies Out itself?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde if you don't know what a static library is, then google it.